# PDOStatement::fetchAll returns array and adds null to the end

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I've got a weird problem. When doing a simple mysql query it returns the correct values but adds *null* to the end of the array. This causes a lot of troubles since when I loop through the array it adds *null* to every value:

**Query**

```
$keyword_results = $conn->prepare("SELECT title,link, position, status FROM keyword_results WHERE keyword_id = :keyword_id");
$keyword_results->bindParam(':keyword_id', $get_keyword_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$keyword_results->execute();
```

**Print Array**

```
$db_results = $keyword_results->fetchAll();
print_r($db_results);
```

**Result**

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
      [title] => Title 
      [0] => Title 
      [link] => http://www.link.com/ 
      [1] => http://www.link.com/ 
      [position] => 1 
      [2] => 1 
      [status] => new 
      [3] => new  
  )
  [1] => Array ( 
      [title] => Title 
      [0] => Title 
      [link] => http://www.link.com/ 
      [1] => http://www.link.com/ 
      [position] => 1 
      [2] => 1 
      [status] => new 
      [3] => new  
  )
) null
```

**Possible reason?**

Before I query the database I check if the keyword already exist in the database. I do this by doing a query with count(*) and then wrap the code above in the following `if statement`

```
if($keyword_check->fetchColumn()) {...}
```

Not sure if this is the reason but its all I can think of...

Anyone an idea where this *null* at the end of the array comes from? If you need more information please let me know and I am happy to provide whatever is needed to solve this problem.

Cheers!

Comment: I think its due to print_r try to see if the same happens when using var_dump

Comment: Thanks @meda, just tried var_dump but it also adds null to the end of the array. :(

Comment: Why are you checking if the keyword exists? If it didn't exist, then the main query should just return no results.

Comment: @General_Twyckenham, yeah, while writing it I noticed the same thing. Will update this then... :)

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you aren't printing or dumping another null variable?

Comment: @Arth, this is all the code I have. Really don"t know what is going on..

Comment: Try printing your array twice in a row and see if the null comes up twice.. I'm fairly sure that null is coming from somewhere else because it is outside the array's closing bracket.

Comment: OK, started from scratch and now it works. Still don't know what causes this issue but it has been solved now. Thanks all for trying to help and sorry for wasting your time. Cheers! :)